# box2dlights confuses ScreenUtils for screenshots in libGDX

Tags: libgdx

I take screenshots as usual in libGDX via `ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap()`, which works fine. Hoever, when I call `RayHandler.updateAndRender()` during rendering, then the screenshot only contains those assets rendered *after* this call. All other pixels in the screenshot are transparent.

What is the best way to deal with this issue?